using the variable img is redundant?
first i have to say that the code is working perfect.
but i concern that using this way the img variable is redundant because i have also the variable _originalImage.
the code in the top of the class:
    private bool _DisplayFocusCues = true;
    private Image _originalImage;
    private Image _clickImage;
    private Image img;

    public CustomButton()
    {
        this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent on click
        this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent on hover
        this.DisplayFocusCues = false;

        // Assume Properties.Resources.YourImageResource is the resource identifier for your image
        img = ResizeImage(Properties.Resources.icons8_record_32, 50, 50);
        this.Image = img;
        this.Size = img.Size;
        _originalImage = img;
    }

and then in the OnMouseUp event
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
    _originalImage = img;
    this.Image = _originalImage;
}

the reason i'm using the img variable because when using it that way in the OnMouseUp event it's making the button click effect of clicking the button changing the colors.
without the img variable when i click the button each time it will keep make the button color darker and darker and will never return to the button original color.

I haven't tested the following code, but I would assume this would work.
private bool _DisplayFocusCues = true;
private Image _originalImage;
private Image _clickImage;

public CustomButton()
{
    this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent
    this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent on click
    this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // Transparent on hover
    this.DisplayFocusCues = false;

    // Assume Properties.Resources.YourImageResource is the resource identifier for your image
    this.Image = ResizeImage(Properties.Resources.icons8_record_32, 50, 50);
    this.Size = this.Image.Size;
    _originalImage = this.Image;
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
    this.Image = _originalImage;
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
    if (_clickImage != null)
        this.Image = _clickImage;
}

